# Trying to press key in input field using key event

Tags: javascript, input, keyevent

I'm trying to press a key in an input field to simulate typing in a field, but the key I press does not show up.

I try to first set a key event then dispatch it to the input field. It appears to work in terms of the event firing correctly except the key I press does not show up in the input field.

Why doesn't the key I press show up in the field as if I typed it?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type=button onClick=doit() value=clickme>
    <input type=text id="texty" value="foo" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
  </body>
</html>

<script>

  function simulateKeyEvent(character) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    evt.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, false, window,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, character.charCodeAt(0));
    textfield.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
  textfield = document.getElementById("texty");

  function doit(){
    textfield.value="bar";
    textfield.focus();
    simulateKeyEvent("A");
    simulateKeyEvent("B");
    simulateKeyEvent("C");
  }

  function myFunction(event) {
    keynum = event.which;
    alert("You pressed a key"+String.fromCharCode(keynum));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No it is not a duplicate of that one. He does not want to handle the kreypress, he wants to generate one

Comment: You could make the event handler append the character to the field value.

Comment: I'm trying to input the characters without using javascript to change the value because the website only does validation when someone actually presses keys in the field.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of those questions.